# How to change the "html" tag attributes?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have in Site.css:

```
html { height:200px; }
```

I want to do the same thing from javascript. So I tried: `html.style...` and `document.style...` but they don't work. How *is* it done?

Comment: You need to give us more context. Are you attempting to set the height of your page?

Comment: @TheCapn Not "page", "html". If you meant the page in general... - yes.

Comment: Well the "html" tag wraps the entire contents of the html page as the parent element. Would you not want to set "height" on a element of <body> and not the entire page itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<html>` element is `document.documentElement`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Using **javascript**:

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
html.style.height = 200px;
```

Using **jQuery**:

```
$("html").css("height","200px");
```

Comment: OK. I'm not using that. But thanks.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a *NodeList* which won't have a `style` property.

Comment: Yes. As @Quentin said - this doesn't work.

Comment: @ispiro you can use 'document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]' see the update.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery, select html tag and change it's css by passing key and value in css function

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('html').css('height','200px');
 })
```